# Is it possible to have IIS create websites dynamically based on a git branch? If so, how would I go about it?

Tags: iis

The title pretty much says it all.

Currently we use Bamboo and we deploy to three environments (testing,staging,production). During feature development, we'll create a branch, and eventually push that branch to testing for QA. The downside is that if we have another branch we need to test, we have to wait until that one is finished being tested before moving the next one. I figured, it would make sense to have "sites" dynamically created for those branches. Maybe those branches use different ports? Or if possible, use the branch name.

Any links or suggestions to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

**Update:**

I partially have this working. Still a bit to go though.

I'm using a script task in Bamboo that will create the physical directory for the branch.

I then use `APPCMD` to create a new app targeting that directory.

My new challenge is either figuring out how to override the default connection string in `Web.config` or use web deploy and override the location that it deploys to. Both seem to be giving me different headaches.

Comment: Check what exactly creates the sites onIIs and modify that part (which is not in IIS itself). Very likely you need to refer to Bamboo documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm curious if there is a way for IIS to just read that there's a new directory and serve that as a site. I can deploy to the wwwroot directory on my server. Maybe I can access the site via `ip.add.re.ss:port/branch-name` or something like that. Though accessing like that currently gives me a 503.

Comment: IIS cannot. Give that up and do the proper configuration.